# Rotation Animation for ItemTemplate in GridView - C# - UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a `GridView` in my app which has a `Template` and this `Template` includes a couple of `TextBlock` items and an `Image` inside a `StackPanel`. I want to Rotate the `StackPanel` in Z axis (preferably, as you can say vertically - not in circular way - as in Sims 3 you can rotate a character) (**correct me if I am wrong and it is not Z axis.**) but I am not able to do that since Template part of the `GridView` cannot be accessed from outside the template. So the `DoubleAnimation` returns an error that the name of the element was not found. I even tried to set the target to the `Title` of my `ItemsClass` for my Template but still it says the name was not found.

So is there anyway to achieve this?
I am trying the following code for now.

Favorites.xaml

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind TVFavoritesList, Mode=OneWay}"
                      x:Name="TVDataGrid"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      Height="350"
                      Margin="10"
                      IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                      ItemClick="dataGrid_ItemClick"
                      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Auto"
                      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled">
                <GridView.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text=""
                               x:Name="TVFavoritesHeader"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               TextAlignment="Center"
                               Margin="5,0"/>
                </GridView.Header>
                <GridView.HeaderTransitions>
                    <TransitionCollection>
                        <EdgeUIThemeTransition/>
                    </TransitionCollection>
                </GridView.HeaderTransitions>
                <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <GridView.ItemContainerTransitions>
                    <TransitionCollection>
                        <PaneThemeTransition Edge="Top"/>
                    </TransitionCollection>
                </GridView.ItemContainerTransitions>
                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:ItemsClass">
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,10,10,10"
                                    Name="rotateme"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    BorderBrush="Red"
                                    BorderThickness="0,1"
                                    IsRightTapEnabled="True"
                                    PointerEntered="TVItemPanel_PointerEntered"
                                    RightTapped="ItemPanel_RightTapped">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="Title"
                                        Text="{x:Bind ItemTitle, Mode=OneWay}"
                                        TextAlignment="Center"
                                        TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                        Height="40"
                                        Width="200"/>
                            <Image x:Name="CoverImage"
                                    Source="{x:Bind ItemImageLink, Mode=OneWay}"
                                    Width="180"
                                    Height="250"
                                    Margin="0"/>
                            <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/newcontent.png"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   Visibility="{x:Bind ItemUpdate, Mode=OneWay}"
                                   Width="150"
                                   Margin="0,-250,0,0"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ItemType, Mode=OneWay}"
                                        TextAlignment="Center"
                                        TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                                <RotateTransform/>
                            </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>


<Page.Resources>
<Storyboard x:Name="AnimationStoryboard">
<DoubleAnimation x:Name="RotateAnimation" To="360" RepeatBehavior="1"
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)">
</DoubleAnimation>
</Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>
```

Favorites.xaml.cs

```
private void TVItemPanel_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
        var pointer = (StackPanel)sender;
        var item = (ItemsClass)((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource).DataContext;
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(RotateAnimation, pointer.Name);
        //Storyboard.SetTargetName(RotateAnimation, item.ItemTitle);
        AnimationStoryboard.Begin();
}
```

ItemsClass.cs

```
namespace WatchfreeWebsite
{
public class ItemsClass
  {

    public int ItemID
    { get; set; }

    public string ItemTitle
    { get; set; }

    public string ItemType
    { get; set; }

    public string ItemImageLink
    { get; set; }

    public string ItemPageLink
    { get; set; }

    public Visibility ItemUpdate
    { get; set; }
  }
}
```

This is only the relevant part (of the entire code) that corresponds to the animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, it seems you want to rotate the `StackPanel` when pointer entered. If so, you can try with following code:

```
private StackPanel CurrentTarget;

private void TVItemPanel_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var pointer = (StackPanel)sender;
    if (AnimationStoryboard.GetCurrentState() == ClockState.Active && CurrentTarget.Equals(pointer))
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        AnimationStoryboard.Stop();

        Storyboard.SetTarget(RotateAnimation, pointer);

        AnimationStoryboard.Begin();
        CurrentTarget = pointer;
    }
}
```

Here we should use [**Storyboard.SetTarget**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.storyboard.settarget) method instead of [**Storyboard.SetTargetName**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.storyboard.settargetname.aspx) method as your `StackPanel` in `DataTemplate` and there will be a lot of `StackPanel`s with the **same name** when the `GridView` loaded.

Besides this, we also need to stop current animation when pointer moving into other `StackPanel`. If not, we might get error like:

> Operation is not valid on an active Animation or Storyboard.  Root Storyboard must be stopped first.

So I defined a `CurrentTarget` field to store current target `StackPanel`.

At last, you may also need to modify `RotateAnimation` as `RepeatBehavior="1"` specifies **one day** which is not logical to me and to specifies **one time** we should use **`RepeatBehavior="1x"`**. For more info, please see **XAML Values** of [RepeatBehavior structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.repeatbehavior.aspx).

Comment: Yes, I achieved the animation myself before your answer but couldn't write here soon. But your answer is right. Thank you